# Lua/Corona sdk error

Tags: lua, coronasdk, null

I'm having this issue, and I can't find a solution:

"level1.lua:161 attempt to index global 'crate' (a nil value)"

It happens when it should change the crate position on line 161, but "centerX + (centerX * event.xGravity" does not return nil, cause the "textMessage" show the correct value.

Code below

```
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    --
    -- level1.lua
    --
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
    local scene = storyboard.newScene()

    -- include Corona's "physics" library
    local physics = require "physics"
    physics.start(); physics.pause()

    --------------------------------------------
    -- Sounds
    local shakeSound = audio.loadSound ("shake.mp3")

    -- Display, metrics stuff
    local centerX = display.contentWidth / 2
    local centerY = display.contentHeight / 2

    -- forward declarations and other locals
    local screenW, screenH, halfW = display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight, display.contentWidth*0.5

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- BEGINNING OF YOUR IMPLEMENTATION
    --
    -- NOTE: Code outside of listener functions (below) will only be executed once,
    --       unless storyboard.removeScene() is called.
    --
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    -- Text parameters
    local labelx = 50
    local x = 220
    local y = 95
    local fontSize = 24

    local frameUpdate = false                   -- used to update our Text Color (once per frame)

    local xglabel = display.newText( "gravity x = ", labelx, y, native.systemFont, fontSize )
    xglabel:setTextColor(255,255,255)




    local textMessage = function( str, location, scrTime, size, color, font )

        local x, t

        size = tonumber(size) or 24
        color = color or {255, 255, 255}
        font = font or "Helvetica"

        -- Determine where to position the text on the screen
        if "string" == type(location) then
            if "Top" == location then
                x = display.contentHeight/4
            elseif "Bottom" == location then
                x = (display.contentHeight/4)*3
            else
                -- Assume middle location
                x = display.contentHeight/2
            end
        else
            -- Assume it's a number -- default to Middle if not
            x = tonumber(location) or display.contentHeight/2
        end

        scrTime = (tonumber(scrTime) or 3) * 1000       -- default to 3 seconds (3000) if no time given

        t = display.newText(str, 0, 0, font, size )
        t.x = display.contentWidth/2
        t.y = x
        t:setTextColor( color[1], color[2], color[3] )

        -- Time of 0 = keeps on screen forever (unless removed by calling routine)
        --
        if scrTime ~= 0 then

            -- Function called after screen delay to fade out and remove text message object
            local textMsgTimerEnd = function()
                transition.to( t, {time = 500, alpha = 0},
                    function() t.removeSelf() end )
            end

            -- Keep the message on the screen for the specified time delay
            timer.performWithDelay( scrTime, textMsgTimerEnd )
        end

        return t        -- return our text object in case it's needed

    end -- textMessage()




    -- Called when the scene's view does not exist:
    function scene:createScene( event )
        local group = self.view

        -- create a grey rectangle as the backdrop
        local background = display.newRect( 0, 0, screenW, screenH )
        background:setFillColor( 128 )

        -- make a crate (off-screen), position it, and rotate slightly
        local crate = display.newImage('crate.png') --display.newImageRect( "crate.png", 90, 90 )
        crate.x = centerX
        crate.y = centerY
        crate.rotation = 15

        -- add physics to the crate
        physics.addBody( crate, { density=1.0, friction=0.3, bounce=0.3 } )

        -- create a grass object and add physics (with custom shape)
        local grass = display.newImageRect( "grass.png", screenW, 82 )
        grass:setReferencePoint( display.BottomLeftReferencePoint )
        grass.x, grass.y = 0, display.contentHeight

        -- define a shape that's slightly shorter than image bounds (set draw mode to "hybrid" or "debug" to see)
        local grassShape = { -halfW,-34, halfW,-34, halfW,34, -halfW,34 }
        physics.addBody( grass, "static", { friction=0.3, shape=grassShape } )

        -- all display objects must be inserted into group
        group:insert( background )
        group:insert( grass)
        group:insert( crate )
    end

    -- Called immediately after scene has moved onscreen:
    function scene:enterScene( event )
        local group = self.view

        physics.start()

    end

    -- Called when scene is about to move offscreen:
    function scene:exitScene( event )
        local group = self.view

        physics.stop()

    end

    -- If scene's view is removed, scene:destroyScene() will be called just prior to:
    function scene:destroyScene( event )
        local group = self.view

        package.loaded[physics] = nil
        physics = nil
    end

    -- Accelerometer
    local function onAccelerate( event )


        -- Move our object based on the accelerator values  --
        textMessage( tostring(centerX + (centerX * event.xGravity)), "naosei", 0.5, 12, {255, 255, 0} )
        crate.x = centerX + (centerX * event.xGravity)
        crate.y = centerY + (centerY * event.yGravity * -1)

        -- sound beep if Shake'n
        if event.isShake == true then
        textMessage( "Shake!", "Top", 3, 52, {255, 255, 0} )
            audio.play( shakeSound )
        end
    end

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- END OF YOUR IMPLEMENTATION
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Add runtime listeners
    Runtime:addEventListener ("accelerometer", onAccelerate);

    -- Add scene listeners
    -- "createScene" event is dispatched if scene's view does not exist
    scene:addEventListener( "createScene", scene )

    -- "enterScene" event is dispatched whenever scene transition has finished
    scene:addEventListener( "enterScene", scene )

    -- "exitScene" event is dispatched whenever before next scene's transition begins
    scene:addEventListener( "exitScene", scene )

    -- "destroyScene" event is dispatched before view is unloaded, which can be
    -- automatically unloaded in low memory situations, or explicitly via a call to
    -- storyboard.purgeScene() or storyboard.removeScene().
    scene:addEventListener( "destroyScene", scene )

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    return scene
```

Answer (score 3):

> "level1.lua:161 attempt to index global 'crate' (a nil value)"

Because there is no `crate` variable in scope on line 161.

You do have a variable named `crate` inside of `createScene` but it's *local*, so it's only visible within that function. Line 161 is a different function (`onAccelerate`), there is no local `crate` variable in scope there, so Lua looks for a global (`_G['crate']`), gets back `nil`, and you try to index that. Hence the error.

Easiest fix: remove the keyword `local` from the `crate` on line 108, so you create a global. It's not pretty, but it should work.

Comment: Thank you, it was 3a.m when I get this error, I think my brain was needing to rest.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid using global variables because of memory leak issues.
What I do is define the display object names in the root scope and then set them from within the createScene function. I think this helps lua to do garbage collection.

```
local background, crate

function scene:createScene( event )
    local group = self.view
    local background = display.newRect( 0, 0, screenW, screenH )
    local crate = display.newImage('crate.png')
    group:insert( background )
    group:insert( crate )
end
```

Comment: @jusliusbangert in order for lua to garbage collect your `crate` variable, you will have to set it to nil somewhere, or this would have to be created within a limited scope. In other case it won't work.